# Nested DIV table displays incorrectly

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have problems coding a nested DIV table:

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
}

.divTableCell,
.divTableHead {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableFoot {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.divTable2 {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.divTable2Row {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTable2Cell,
.divTable2Body {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">

    <div class="divTableRow">
      <!-- this row contains a nested 2x2 table -->
      <div class="divTableCell">outer left </div>
      <div class="divTableCell">outer right
        <div class="divTable2">
          <div class="divTable2Body">
            <div class="divTable2Row">
              <div class="divTable2Cell">inner 1st line left</div>
              <div class="divTable2Cell">inner 1st line right</div>
            </div>
            <div class="divTable2Row">
              <div class="divTable2Cell">inner 2nd line left</div>
              <div class="divTable2Cell">inner 2nd line right</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="divTableRow">
      <!-- no nested table here -->
      <div class="divTableCell">outer left</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">outer right</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- end div divTable Body -->
</div>
<!-- end div divTable -->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jsrookey/0z0agxad/

The nested table cells are not on the same table row line, but underneath each other, strangely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `.divTable2Cell` has `display: table-row-group;` instead of `display: table-cell;`.

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
}

.divTableCell,
.divTable2Cell,
.divTableHead {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableFoot {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.divTable2 {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.divTable2Row {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTable2Body {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">

    <div class="divTableRow">
      <!-- this row contains a nested 2x2 table -->
      <div class="divTableCell">outer left </div>
      <div class="divTableCell">outer right
        <div class="divTable2">
          <div class="divTable2Body">
            <div class="divTable2Row">
              <div class="divTable2Cell">inner 1st line left</div>
              <div class="divTable2Cell">inner 1st line right</div>
            </div>
            <div class="divTable2Row">
              <div class="divTable2Cell">inner 2nd line left</div>
              <div class="divTable2Cell">inner 2nd line right</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="divTableRow">
      <!-- no nested table here -->
      <div class="divTableCell">outer left</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">outer right</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- end div divTable Body -->
</div>
<!-- end div divTable -->
```

FWIW you have some unnecessary duplication in CSS classes, i.e. the following are the same:

- `.divTable`, `.divTable2`
- `.divTableBody`, `.divTable2Body`
- `.divTableRow`, `.divTable2Row`
- `.divTableCell`, `.divTable2Cell`
- etc.

Merge them into a single class.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.thead {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tfoot {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.td,
.th {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tbody">
    <div class="tr">
    
      <div class="td">outer left </div>
      <div class="td">outer right
      
        <div class="table">
        
          <div class="tbody">
          
            <div class="tr">
              <div class="td">inner 1st line left</div>
              <div class="td">inner 1st line right</div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="tr">
              <div class="td">inner 2nd line left</div>
              <div class="td">inner 2nd line right</div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
          
        </div><!-- .table -->
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
    
      <div class="td">outer left</div>
      <div class="td">outer right</div>
      
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! Yep, I was actually hoping that I could use the same definitions for all class 'couples' I had defined before.